# default Row Editor input css looks bad

Tags: extjs

I've noticed that when activating the row editor all the inputs css change and they look bad (like they are moving down)

for example : when clicking on phone , the input moves down.

Any idea how to fix it ?

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/mvp

[image]

******   **UPDATE 1**  ******

I've applied the css solution to live

and the css fix

```
.x-form-text {
    display: inherit;
}
```

but it still doesn't work , using chrome inspector I see the css is ignored.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a Chrome 43 related issue, just add the following CSS to your project

```
.x-form-text {
    display: inherit;
}
```

Please, check your fiddle again.

Thanks

Comment: For some reason it doesn't work on my live example but does work on fiddle , I've updated my question with findings.

Comment: My original question was updated with the css , I've supplied url to live example , hope you can shed some light why the fix is being ignored there.

Comment: You have to add your custom CSS after the framework's CSS is added, this is why it is being replaced. If you are using Sencha Command to build your app, add this CSS file to the css block of your app.json file.

Comment: yep , this sort the issue , adding it to app.json instead of including it in the html

Comment: In the html you would have to add after ExtJS' microloader was called.

Comment: once I put it in app.json I don't need it anymore in the html , no ?

Comment: That's right, and this is the way you should be doing it. But if you want to add it to your index.html (in case you wanna test without rebuild the application), you have to add it after the microloader.

Comment: May I ask you something over email ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79241/discussion-between-guilherme-lopes-and-alophind).